# Are PHP sessions affected by resetting IIS or the application pool?

Tags: php, session, iis

I'm running PHP 5.5 on a Windows 2012 box with IIS as the web server. The PHP sessions are set to write to files. If I do an iisreset, are the PHP sessions of logged in users lost or do they continue on as if nothing happened? What about recycling the app pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since php sessions are identified by a session id stored in a cookie if you do a iisreset those should not have proplem when a script tries to do a session_start().